# How to get a count of every item in a list?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Context:

I have a program that parses log files for connection attempts on my box.
It pulls a list of ip addresses and then I have other functions I want to run on this list of information, and one in particular isn't working as intended. It's supposed to get a count of connection attempts per country.

Code - ip_tools.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import requests
import json
import socket

#function to get the ip address of the host user
def get_host_ipad():
    host_ip_request = requests.get("http://ipinfo.io/ip")
    return host_ip_request.text

#function to get gelocation info of a remote host
def get_rhost_geo(ipad):
    full_geo_info = {}
    rhost_ip_request = requests.get("http://ipinfo.io/%s/json" % (ipad))
    json_response = json.loads(rhost_ip_request.text)
    for value in json_response:
        full_geo_info.update({str(value) : str(json_response[value])})
    return full_geo_info

#function to return country of rhost
def get_geo_country(ipad):
    geo_info = get_rhost_geo(ipad)
    geo_country = geo_info["country"]
    return geo_country

#function to perform reverse dns lookup
def get_rhost_url(ipad):
    try:
        rhost_url = socket.gethostbyaddr(ipad)
        rhost_url = rhost_url[0]
    except Exception:
        rhost_url = 'No URL found for this ip address.'
    return rhost_url



#main function to run the code only if called directly
def Main():

#printing the options menu and taking a variable to be passed
    print '_' * 20
    print "1: Get your ip address: \n"
    print "2: Get Geolocation of an IP address: \n"
    print "3: Atempt getting URL from IP address"
    sel = raw_input("Choose an option: \n")

#if statement to control menu navigation
    if sel == '1':
        print get_host_ipad()

#calls the get_rhost_ipad function defined above on user input
    elif sel == '2':
        ipad = raw_input("Which IP address?: \n")
        print get_rhost_geo(ipad)
    elif sel == 'quit':
        quit()
    elif sel == '3':
        ipad = raw_input("Which IP address?: \n")
        print get_rhost_url(ipad)

    else:
        print "Please choose one of the other options. \n"

if __name__=="__main__":
        Main()
```

Code - log_auditor.py:

```
import re
import ip_tools

#global variable to open kippo log in read mode

MY_LOG = open("/path/to/log", "r").read()

#function to get ip address from log file with a regular expression
def get_ips_from_log():
    re_ip_search = re.findall(r"\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b", MY_LOG)
    return re_ip_search

#function to get attempts per unique ip address
def get_ip_count():
    ip_log = get_ips_from_log()
    ip_count = [(i, ip_log.count(i)) for i in set(ip_log)]
    return ip_count


#function to get attempts per country
def get_country_count():
    ip_list = get_ips_from_log()
    get_country_count = [(ip_tools.get_geo_country(ip), ip_list.count(ip)) for ip in set(ip_list)]
    return get_country_count

#main function to only run program when called:

def Main():
    print get_country_count()

if __name__=='__main__':
    Main()
```

The function in question is this one:

```
#function to get attempts per country
def get_country_count():
    ip_list = get_ips_from_log()
    get_country_count = [(ip_tools.get_geo_country(ip), ip_list.count(ip)) for ip in set(ip_list)]
    return get_country_count
```

unfortunately its output looks like:

```
[('CN', 2), ('CN', 566), ('NL', 2), ('CN', 3040), ('CN', 2), ('CN', 1042), ('CN', 2), ('US', 2), ('KR', 382), ('DE', 2), ('US', 127)]
```

How do I get this grouped even further?

Comment: Can you post your expected output?

Comment: Your problem can be explained using one example input list, one function (the one you indicated) and an example of desired output. Please narrow down your problem - people aren't really interested in the story of your life ;)

Comment: What do you mean by 'get this grouped even further'?

Comment: @Zenadix OP probably wants counts of `'CN'` for example added together, so instead of many results `('CN', 2), ..., ('CN', 2)` they want only one per label: `('CN', 4)`.

Comment: Once you remove all the extraneous stuff, I think all you're looking for something like `collections.Counter(ip_tools.get_geo_country(ip) for ip in ip_list)`, in which case this is a duplicate of lots of "how do I count things" questions.

Comment: Expected output should have no more than one occurance of each country code. There are multiples for China ('CN'), the total count for all of them should be under just one listing, not 6+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a dictionary to keep track of the total count for each country code.

```
from collections import defaultdict
def get_country_count():
    ip_list = get_ips_from_log()
    country_count = defaultdict(int)
    for ip in set(ip_list):
        country_count[ip_tools.get_geo_country(ip)] += ip_list.count(ip)
    return country_count
```

Comment: Beautiful, I wasn't aware of this library. The output is now as follows:

`defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'NL': 2, 'CN': 4654, 'DE': 2, 'US': 141, 'KR': 448, 'ID': 14})`

how do I remove the 

defaultdict(<type 'int'>, ?

Ultimately as long as the information is in a dictionary or a list of tuples it should work for what I need.

Comment: Use the dict constructor `dict(country_count)` which will print `{'NL' : 2, 'CN': 4654, 'DE': 2, 'US': 141, 'KR': 448, 'ID': 14}`

Comment: Very easy, I should have thought of that. Thanks for the help, I'm still pretty new to all of this

Comment: This seems like a lot of work to simulate what a one-liner with `collections.Counter` would do, except in quadratic time instead of linear. Why?

Answer (score 0):

If we don't touch all other code, function can be rewrited like this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

....

def get_country_count():
    country_count = defaultdict(int)
    for ip in get_ips_from_log():
        country_count[ip_tools.get_geo_country(ip)] += 1
    return country_count
```

or if it costs a lot to use `get_geo_country`:

```
def get_country_count():
    country_count = defaultdict(int)
    ip_list = get_ips_from_log()
    for ip in set(ip_list):
        country_count[ip_tools.get_geo_country(ip)] += ip_list.count(ip)
    return country_count
```

`defaultdict` used only for a reason don't write ugly construction like this:

```
def get_country_count():
   ....
   for ....
       country = ip_tools.get_geo_country(ip)
       if country in country_count:
           country_count[country] += ...
       else:
           country_count[country] = ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Some one else also mentioned using defaultdict, I didn't even know that existed but that is super helpful. The second code snippet is the one I will be using.